# Operations on different data types

Tags: c, type-conversion

When i was dividing a int variable with a float variable, it was giving correct answer. I thought data types needed typecasting to be, for one data type cant operate with another kind of data type. If not, then how does the processor decide it can operate int and float, but not int and char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where you have not explicitly typecast the variables, implicit typecasting is performed. An example of how implicit typecasting works :

int variable = (int / float )  -> variable will have an integer value.

float variable = (int / float )  -> variable will have a float value.

An example using char and int :

```
int a=0; 
char c='c'; 
a = c; 
cout<<"Ascii value of"<<c<<"is "<<a;
```

Comment: Is it the same with operations on int and char? Implicit typecasting?

Comment: Yes if you try to assign a char to an int, it will most probably store the ascii value of the char to the int variable.